# List become a nested list when passed through a procedure

Tags: tcl

I'm a beginner who just recently learned some TCL and recently came across a puzzling TCL internal process that I cannot explain. I have the code below:

```
proc print_items{args} {
    foreach item $args {
        puts $item
    }
}

set arr "A B C D"
print_items $arr
```

I was expecting the result to be:

```
A
B
C
D
```

but it was:

```
A B C D
```

Upon closer inspection. I noticed that $args was not the flat list I thought but instead was

```
> puts $args
{A B C D}
> llength $args
1
```

That means $args itself must have been wrapped in another list i.e $args must've been like this when received by the procedure: {{A B C D}}

**So my question is: Why does TCL wrapped an already formed list in another list when passed inside print_items? This is very different from other programming languages that I've done. In which circumstances does the argument gets wrapped in another data structure (i.e: in another list, dictionary, array, etc.)?**

Comment: Your example will work as expected, if you expand the variable `arr`'s value into its elements using the {*} operator, each then becoming an argument to the called procedure: `print_items {*}$arr`. This will look for the called proc like you would have written: `print_items A B C D`. As the others noted, `args` handling will then combine the separate arguments into a list again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword "args" in procedure arguments has a special meaning. It collects all parameters to a tcl list. For example:

```
proc foo { param1 param2 args } {
    # here:
    #     $param1 = alice
    #     $param2 = bob
    #     $args = {alice1 bob1 alice2 bob2}
}
foo alice bob alice1 bob1 alice2 bob2
```

Thus, the answer for your question is: don't use the special word "args" as a prodecure argument because it is processes in a special way. Try to use any other name for procedure agrument.

Comment: Technically, `args` is currently only special when it is the final formal argument... but this may change in the future if we put a more complex argument parser in the procedure implementation code.

Comment: This is what I thought `args` would be inside the procedure body but it turned out to be a nested list i.e in the example you give, it would be `{{alice1 bob1 alice2 bob2}}` and iterating through it would result in giving `{alice1 bob1 alice2 bob2}` and not the individual elements of `args` passed in.

Comment: No, Chpock is correct. The difference between this answer and your question is that you are passing a string containing whitespace as a single argument into `args`, so in your proc you have args = `{"A B C D"}` -- which is a list with a single element. Perhaps the confusion is that when you print it, Tcl will use braces instead of quotes in the output.